# Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Error Help

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey guys When I requested ajax request a web service I m gettig this error with this code.. But Not every computer just laptops :) I don't understand... it works with desktop computer

ajax request from this site http://www.mozturk.somee.com/main.html

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mozturk.somee.com/icerik.asmx/makaleGetir. Origin http://www.mozturk.somee.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
$.ajax({

```
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.mozturk.somee.com/icerik.asmx/makaleGetir',
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (results) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Bağlantı sırasında bir sorun oluştu. Yeniden deneyin');
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost certainly misdiagnosing the problem and testing:

- `http://mozturk.somee.com/main.html` on the laptops
- `http://www.mozturk.somee.com/main.html` on the desktop.

Since you use an absolute URI in the request, you end up mixing origins.

Use a relative URI instead.

(I also suggest you pick either *mozturk.somee.com* **or** *www.mozturk.somee.com* to be canonical and redirect all the traffic from the other to it).

Comment: thanks it has to be same url I mean subdomain mozturk.somee.com  and ajax request starts with mozturk.somee.com not www.mozturk.somee.com thanks again.